# Deployed dll file is not the one built by TFS

Tags: tfs, msbuild, continuous-integration, tfsbuild

I have a TFS 2013 build definition that recently started to act strange. Its been doing its job for over a year now without any problems.

It builds 4 different projects. Two of them are asp.net mvc/webapi projects which also are deployed via msdeploy to two separate websites on the same QA staging web server. The build is configured to use Release|Any CPU

When the build runs the dll version is set using the ApplyVersionToAssemblys powershell script.

In the build folder all the assemblies have the correct version. But in one of the deployed web sites one of the dll files "WebUI.dll" has version number 1.0.0.0 ie not the same as the same dll in build directory has which is 4.0.buildnumber

The deployed "WebUI.dll" also seems to be built in Debug mode becuase some buttons and actions are only displayed when DEBUG is defined.

If I copy the built WebUI.dll from build directory or even the PublishedWebsites directory everything works as expected.

So my question is how can MSDeploy via MSBuild create its "own" version of the WebUI.dll? (And no - the Define DEBUG constant checkbox is not checked in Release mode). The version 1.0.0 WebUI.dll cant be found anywhere on the server so I guess it must be "created" when msdeploy runs?

(The only change I've made recently is to add a new build definition which builds the same solution and runs all tests but does not deploy anything.)

UPDATE: I tried to publish from VS using the same publish profile used by the build process and that works as expected. The WebUI.dll deployed is built in release mode. The version is not applied becuase that is part of the build process but the important thing is that its the Release mode dll that is deployed and not Debug which is the case when the buildprocess does the deploy. I also tried creating a web deploy package and installed that on the local server with the same result.

So the problem is still that the WebUI.dll built in the build process is correct (Release mode and correct versioning) - but gets "replaced" during the deploy on the build server by a Debug mode and without versoning

UPDATE 2; Msbuild cmd

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\amd64\MSBuild.exe /nologo /noconsolelogger "C:\Builds\2\Products\SomeApp4.Main\src\SomeApp4\Main\Source\SomeApp4.Web.sln" /nr:False /fl /flp:"logfile=C:\Builds\2\Products\SomeApp4.Main\src\SomeApp4\Main\Source\SomeApp4.Web.log;encoding=Unicode;verbosity=normal" /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=Chicago /p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=true /p:Password=bw /m /p:OutDir="C:\Builds\2\Products\SomeApp4.Main\bin\SomeApp4.Web\\" /p:Configuration="Release" /p:Platform="Any CPU" /p:VCBuildOverride="C:\Builds\2\Products\SomeApp4.Main\src\SomeApp4\Main\Source\SomeApp4.Web.sln.Any CPU.Release.vsprops" /dl:WorkflowCentralLogger,"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 12.0\Tools\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Server.Logger.dll";"Verbosity=Normal;BuildUri=vstfs:///Build/Build/740;IgnoreDuplicateProjects=False;InformationNodeId=14;TargetsNotLogged=GetNativeManifest,GetCopyToOutputDirectoryItems,GetTargetPath;LogProjectNodes=True;LogWarnings=True;TFSUrl=http://boston.SomeCompany.local:8080/tfs/SomeCompany;"*WorkflowForwardingLogger,"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 12.0\Tools\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Server.Logger.dll";"Verbosity=Normal;" /p:BuildId="abd7db3d-4ff8-43b4-ab36-f35c6f6e5697,vstfs:///Build/Build/740" /p:BuildLabel="SomeApp4.Main_4.0.6.740_20160121_103558" /p:BuildTimestamp="Thu, 21 Jan 2016 09:35:59 GMT" /p:BuildSourceVersion="LSomeApp4.Main_4.0.6.740_20160121_103558@$/Products" /p:BuildDefinition="SomeApp4.Main"
```

Comment: Do you get the same result if you publish from VS?  You could also try creating an MSDeploy package and checking the file version inside the package.  I assume you have always used the PowerShell script to set the dll version?

Comment: See my update in the post in reply to your comment. And yes - I've always used the same powershell script. That still works. The files built on the build server are correct (release mode with versoning) but one of the dll files WebUI.dll get replaced during the deploy process - but only in the build process

Comment: Could you share your msdeploy command?

Comment: Yes- see update 2 in the post

Comment: The best suggestion I can give you is start taking out build/deploy options until you find the one that is causing the issue OR the opposite: create a new build slowly add each component of the full build testing along the way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

The build definition builds 4 solutions where one is the WebUI(aspnet mvc) solution and one is an Api solution (asp.net WebApi)

In the Api solution a project was referencing the WebUI project but the WebUI project wasnt in the Api solution.

MSbuild resolved the WebUI project anyways so there were no errors and build + deploy of the api solution worked. But the WebUI project was built in debug mode since it has no solution configuration in Api solution I guess

The problem when msbuild ran the api solution with deploy flag it also managed to deploy the WebUI project built in debug.

So the WebUI project was deployed twice. First the correct one from the WebUI solution and then the wrong debug WebUI compiled with the Api solution.

Doh! Is all I have to say about that.

Thanks for your help guys.

Answer (score 0):

When you change the assembly version, the version under source control won't be changed. You can only change the version which has been copied on your build agent machine. If the source of the msdeploy command point to the project in TFS, you won't get the versioned assembly.

Comment: Yes i know that. And all the assemblies have the correct version number in the build folder, drop folder, and _PublishedWebsites folder including the WebUI.dll. The problem is when the files gets deployed in the build process. The WebUI.dll deployed is not the one in the created in the build but is replaced by a Debug mode WebUI.dll file and I cant understand how/why? I suspected the aspnet_compiler and tried to run the build without BuildMvcViews but the WebUI.dll still gets replaced